# Bookmarklet to open window to URL, wait for load, close window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

Disclaimer: I don't actually expect this is possible due to security issues, but before I give up entirely I had to ask: Is it possible, using a Javascript bookmarklet, to open a window to a URL and have it auto close after that content has loaded?

My usage is to temporarily disable [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) using it's API. The current code I have works on a simple timeout, but I'd like to have it ensure the page loaded before closing the window.

Here's my (expanded) code at the moment:

```
(() => {
    t = prompt('Disable time (seconds)',30);
    if (t) {
        w = window.open(`http://___IP___/admin/api.php?disable=${t}&auth=___APIKEY___`,'pi-disable','left=20,top=20,width=300,height=200');
        setTimeout(() => w.close(), 1000);
    }
})()
```

In case it's not obvious, I don't control the URL output so I can't add script there to have it close, otherwise this would be a non-issue. And for reference, the output is just a JSON string: `{"status":"disabled"}`

Just for kicks, I tried using fetch() or adding an iframe, but as expected those presented other issues (Mixed Content, CORS policy, etc).

Comment: Instead of outputting JSON, output a small HTML doc with a script tag that calls `window.close()`. Untested but that will definitely make sure the page is loaded before closing the window.

Comment: I tested it, and it works fine, as long as the window/tab loading the document is opened from a script, like in your current code. So a simple bookmark won't work because the browser doesn't allow closing a window from script that wasn't also opened by a script.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the comments under the code section: "In case it's not obvious, _I don't control the URL output_ so I can't add script there to have it close"

Comment: Right, I completely missed that. So this isn't your own Pi?

Comment: It's my brother's technically. I guess if I knew how to delve into the code for Pi-hole I could probably add whatever I want, but I don't know the first thing about it.

Comment: You could take a look at the php file in question, `api.php`, and copy the relevant part to a new one called `disable.php`, then change the output to the HTML mentioned above. Although you need basic PHP knowledge to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible with a bookmarklet, because it can only run its code on the one page you press the bookmarklet button on. If you open a window to a new domain, the bookmarklet won't be able to affect it or watch it load.

You could have *another* bookmarklet that you press when the new window opens, but that kind of defeats the point of automation

You could, however, do this with a userscript, which can run automatically when a page is opened. When the API site is opened, have the userscript watch for page load, then post a message telling your bookmarklet that the page is finished loading, and can be closed. Something along the lines of:

```
(() => {
    const t = prompt('Disable time (seconds)',30);
    if (!t) return;
    const w = window.open(`http://___IP___/admin/api.php?disable=${t}&auth=___APIKEY___`,'pi-disable','left=20,top=20,width=300,height=200');
    window.addEventListener('message', (messageEvent) => {
        if (messageEvent.data === 'api page loaded') w.close();
    });
})()
```

and, with a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Watch for API pageload
// @match        http://___IP___/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  window.opener.postMessage('api page loaded', '*');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of making a small userscript to just auto close the window. Although I was just going to add a self.close() in the script rather than call back to the opening window.

Comment: Oh, that's right, opened windows can `.close()` themselves, they don't require the opener to do it for them. Yeah, that's a better approach.